# ReactJS Provider --> Consumer returning undefined when accessing props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I have a context that I am trying to pass from a Provider to a consumer. It was working perfectly but suddenly it's stopped working. Here is an example of my code.

I have a file called AppContext.tsx that is the root of my application and is rendered by index.js

The AppContext.tsx has the following code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { App } from './App';

interface iHigherStateOfContextProps {
username: string;
}

export const higherStateOfContext = React.createContext({} as iHigherStateOfContextProps);

interface IAppContextProps {}

interface IAppContextState {
userName: string;
}


export class AppContext extends React.Component<IAppContextProps, IAppContextState> {
    constructor(props: IAppContextProps) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
userName:"Some Name"
}

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <higherStateOfContext.Provider value={{
                userName: this.state.userName;
            }}>
                <App />
            </higherStateOfContext.Provider>

        </div>
           
        );
    }
}
```

A consumer further down the tree, we will call this TopBar.tsx, exported Navigation element is called from the App.Tsx that is rendered by AppContext.tsx is coded as this....

So App.tsx looks like this...

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TopNavigation from './components/Navigation/TopBar';

export const App = function (props: {  }) { 
    const [appTitle, setAppTitle] = useState<string>("App Name");
    useEffect(() =>
    {
   }, []); 

        return (
            <div>
               {appTitle}
                <TopNavigation />
               
            </div>
        );
    //}
}
```

And this is the code that is in the imported navigation/TopBar.tsx..

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { higherStateOfContext } from '../../AppContext';
const Navigation = () => {
    return (
    <higherStateOfContext.Consumer>
        {({  userName }) => (

            <TopBar userName={userName} />
        )}
    </higherStateOfContext.Consumer>

);
}

export default Navigation;

interface ITopBarProps {
    userName: string;

}

interface ITopsBarState {


}

class TopBar extends React.Component<ITopBarProps, ITopsBarState>   {

    constructor(props: ITopBarProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { };

 render() {
        return (<div>{this.props.userName}</div>); // <----- This is undefined
}
}
```

This issue is that in TopBar.tsx the consumer is returning undefined from the AppContext Provider and thus doesn't render.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hgtftm) with your example code where [userName is displayed](https://react-hgtftm.stackblitz.io/):

Maybe others issue comes from somewhere else. If you modify Navigation render like this:

```
{(contextValue) => {
    console.log("contextValue", contextValue);
    return <TopBar userName={contextValue?.userName} />;
}}
```

You might see what's the context value really looks like.

Comment: Yeah, that was just me writing this code for the example.. That isn't the cause of the issue. I have fixed this example.

Comment: Please look at the stackblitz project where I copied your example, maybe your error comes from somewhere else.

Comment: That is interesting.. What could interfere with it working? The project is a typescript 4.8.3 project in VS2022. It's running React v18.2.0

Comment: Typescript shouldn't be the problem: if you can see your page, it means that typescript has compiled it and it's very unlikely to have a side-effect of the generated code. Can you modify your Navigation render like in my edit?

Comment: Yeah I did that and it's not made any difference. Still undefined.